# Use site background for CSS fixed element

Tags: css, css-position

I have a fixed div "hovering" above the rest of my site through `position: fixed`. However, this is ugly when other site-elements (i.e. text) appear behind the hovering element. I would like to hide elements when they are behind the hovering element, meaning to only show the site background behind it.

Because the site background in a gradient, I can't simply give the floating element it's own background. Is there a way to do this?

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
Some Text
</div>

<div id="text">
  <script>
  for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    document.write("Text text text text<br />")  
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

*edit*: To clarify: I want the background of the fixed element to the same as the site background where the fixed element is currently over. I don't want to put the fixed element above all other content.

Comment: Did't understand what you want actually?

Comment: In simple words he needs an autoadjustable background for the fixed element that imitates the background color for a specific position that the elements is in page(when scrolling down)

Comment: No. It's not possible man.

Comment: I think one thing to embrace here is, that `background` of the element, and its `content` are still (and always are) parts of that same element, so you can't hide one and get the other one revealed at the same time. And since solutions might actually exist, it is nothing more than `css` trickery :)
I was actually wondering why would you need such thing in a first place? What is your motivation behind this design decision?

Comment: @robjez I'm not the designer, just implementing it. But it does look very cool. But I'll guess I am gonna try some JS stuff since a CSS-only solution seems implausible.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see doing this is to set a scroll frame for text and leave the fixed element(which do not need to be fixed anymore) on top of the page

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  z-index: 5;
}

#text{
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
Some Text
</div>
<div id="text">
  <script>
  for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    document.write("Text text text text<br />")  
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately that not what I want. Among other problems the site content doesn't scroll along the right side of the element anymore with this.

Comment: remove `overflow:hidden` from body

Comment: @dtech - for that you could remove fixed `width` from both `body` and `.text` els..

Answer (score 1):

One other route to explore, might be creating an extra "overlay" `fixed` element, pinned to all 4 corners of `viewport`, and giving it you gradient background, along with an opacity:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  background: #fff;
}
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
Some Text
</div>

<div id="text">
  <script>
  for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    document.write("Text text text text<br />")  
  }
  </script>
</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! :)

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%, #83c783 17%, #52b152 33%, #008a00 67%, #005700 83%, #002400 100%);
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  z-index: 5;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
  width: 100% ;
height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
  Some Text
</div>
<div id="text">
  <script>
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      document.write("Text text text text<br />")
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, but where is that scrollable content now? You just "thrown the baby out along with the bathwater" :)

Comment: I dont know what you want then :P but right now its behind xD

Comment: All trick here is to achieve this scrollable content of `.text` element (but not the background) to get hidden behind the fixed element area when scrolled.

Comment: make a element around the two of them with the background. And then the two "Fexed, and text" on top of eachother :D

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @sTx came up with, you could also hide this awkward scrollbars in `webkit`, by:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  z-index: 5;
}

#text{
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
Some Text
</div>
<div id="text">
  <script>
  for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    document.write("Text text text text<br />")  
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can insert a "background-color" in #fixed in css.

Comment: Like I said, the background changes when scrolling. So that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is the only way to achieve this.

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b4ddb4 0%,#83c783 17%,#52b152 33%,#008a00 67%,#005700 83%,#002400 100%);
}
#text{
  padding-top: 87px;
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 200%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #b4ddb4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
Some Text
</div>
<div id="text">
  <script>
  for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    document.write("Text text text text<br />")  
  }
  </script>
</div>
```